# Data synchronization in offline App

Tags: javascript, database, synchronization, couchdb, pouchdb

I'm deploying an app with Cordova ( phoneGap) and I Need to have my data on my App even when it is offline.
I Found PouchDB, but this is the only Solution ?
I Already use CouchDB and PouchDb, But I didn't like the performance ( with not big Database)
This database contains 500000 documents with images

Answer (score 0):

If you need an open-source JavaScript synchronization solution, PouchDB is probably the fastest thing out there, yeah. If you're experiencing poor performance, there are a few possibilities:

1. use `bulkDocs()` instead of multiple `put()` or `post()s`
2. insert Blobs directly instead of base64 images (see [the attachments guide](http://pouchdb.com/guides/attachments.html) for more info).
3. WebSQL has *sliiightly* better performance than IndexedDB in Chrome/Android, for certain tasks (although it's slower for binary data). The SQLite Plugin is the worst in terms of performance; don't use it. See [the adapters guide](http://pouchdb.com/adapters.html) for more detail.

Otherwise, you might have to dip into native solutions like Couchbase Mobile or Firebase.

Comment: thanks for the response. What is the different Between couchDB and Couchbase Mobile ? If i Use CouchBase or Firebase I need to use PouchDb to Replicate on my app? Thanks a lot

Comment: Couchbase Mobile is a native SDK for communicating with CouchDB or Couchbase (primarily). Firebase is a separate product entirely.